# How to push Nutch clrawled data from Mysql to Solr for indexing

Tags: mysql, solr, nutch

I have crawled website using Nutch and stored data into Mysql database following tutorial provided on the http://nlp.solutions.asia/?p=180. Now I want to push crawled data to solr for indexing. I have executed following command from terminal  {APACHE_NUTCH_HOME}/runtime/local/,

```
  bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr/ -reindex
```

this process takes hardly 5 seconds to get completed without any error, although Mysql table has 111 rows.

After this, i opened

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/query for executing queries.
```

Irrespective of the string inside "q" box, I am getting same response for every executed query which is following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <lst name="responseHeader">
     <int name="status">0</int>
     <int name="QTime">1</int>
     <lst name="params">
         <str name="indent">true</str>
         <str name="q">content</str>
         <str name="_">1372233303649</str>
         <str name="wt">xml</str>
     </lst>
 </lst>
 <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0">
 </result>
</response>
```

What is the possible reason behind this or what am i doing wrong?

Comment: what does it show on the terminal when you run the solrindex command?